# How to transmit MPxData to the compute function of Maya

Tags: c++, api, nodes, maya

I have a Maya api (in c++) that is defining an MPxNode, and some main code which is instancing this MPxNode.

How can I pass data to the MPxNode so that the data is accessible from the compute method ?
From main code:

```
myMpxObj=dagMod.createNode("myMpxNode");
```

In MyMPxNode:

```
MStatus myMpxNode::compute( const MPlug& plug, MDataBlock& block )
{
// How to get here values from the main part ?
    return MS::kUnknownParameter;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to get values inside the compute function of a MpxNode, the more efficient way is to get a MDataHandle to your attribute in the MDataBlock.

`findPlug()` is slower but necessary in situations where you don't have access to the datablock such as in the `doit()` method of a command plugin or `draw()` in a locator.

```
MStatus myMpxNode::compute( const MPlug& plug, MDataBlock& block )
{
    if (plug != myOutPlug) return MS::kUnknownParameter;

    int value = block.inputValue(myAttribute).asInt();
    // set output
    return MS::kSuccess;
}
```

Here's the [dependency node example](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_Dependency_graph_plugins_The_basics_htm) from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
int value;
MObject thisObj = thisMObject();
MFnDependencyNode dgNode( thisObj );
dgNode.findPlug("myAttribute").getValue(value);
```